# Flywaydb Spring Boot and Jasypt - flywaydb not able use decrypted property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I did configuration for flywaydb + Spring boot which works perfectly following the link below  https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot

Flyway is using default datasource which is provided to it via application.properties  - entries are

```
spring.datasource.url= <DB_URL>
spring.datasource.username=testdb
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

Now I am adding JASYPT to the app so that I can encrypt the password.

```
  <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

I encrypted password using JASYPT command line and updated it to file i.e

```
spring.datasource.password= ENC(EFXC0ORLK+Uy6f)
```

Then on java side, added a Bean which loads properties using `org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with static method

Also I have made sure that above Bean actually decrypts the password using loggers.

**But whenever I run my app it fails with error FATAL: password authentication failed for user**  -  Somehow spring is using the properties before its getting decrypt.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it looks like a bug in flyway.

Work around is to set `spring.flyway.password=ENC(...)`